# Find the minimum number of operations to transform the matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I'm stuck with this question:

> > Given 2 square matrices **M<sub>1</sub>** and **M<sub>2</sub>** of dimension **m** and containing positive integers, transform the first matrix into the second by applying this operation on **M<sub>1</sub>**: swap integers in adjacent cells if their sum is prime. Print the minimum number of operations required.

Any hints on how to solve this?

If anyone has come across this question before on a programming website, please point it out. I've forgotten where I read this question. Thanks.

Comment: (http://www.codechef.com/problems/H1/)

Comment: Thank you! If you could provide an algorithm it would be great!

Comment: CodeChef's version more or less cries out for breadth-first search, as the search space is small, and test cases consist of several matrices M1 and a fixed matrix M2.

Comment: Yes I read that. I was thinking of an algorithm which would work for size >= 3

Comment: A\*, with the sum of L1 distances over 2 as the heuristic? I suspect that the general problem with an arbitrary swappability relation is NP-hard, of which one implication would be to suggest that there's no obvious polynomial-time algorithm to be found.

Comment: There must be more than this - otherwise a whole lot of assumptions need to be made... e.g. How would you transform `[1 1; 1 2]` into `[1 1; 1 3]` just by swapping entries? What is "adjacent" - vertical/horizontal only, or also diagonal? I'm guessing that the assumption is that `M2` is simply a permutation of `M1`, but even so, my initial impression is that there would be a large subset of possible cases that don't have a solution - you could form a set of numbers such that no sum of two elements is prime (e.g. all even numbers)...

Comment: I forgot to mention in the question, for the test cases given, it is guaranteed that there is a solution (M1 can be transformed into M2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moves in this case are reversible, i.e. if you can do a swap on a matrix then you can do the reverse swap afterward. So if you are given two matrices M1 and M2, one way to reduce the complexity of breadth-first search is to do breadth-first search simultaneously from M1 and M2, one step at a time, and hash the matrices you get in the search and then the minimal path will be found the first time you find a matrix that is reachable from both M1 and M2. This needs a little bit of tweaking because the minimum path length could be odd or even, but the basic idea is simple and it can reduce your total search space complexity from N to N^(1/2) in order to find the answer.